# How delete[] works behind the scene in c++?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

when we allocate memory dynamically using new operator for a int data type. it makes sense to use delete operator.
For example 
if a code would like bellow :
    
`int *p=new int;
delete p;`

Here it makes sense to use delete . Here we can think like this that the block, p points ,delete/de-allocate that memory block .
But for the bellow code :

`int *p=new int[5];
delete[] p;`

How does it make any sense to use delete[] here. I am asking this because p is not the name of the array. Here p is just a simple pointer which is pointing to the first element of the array memory block. Now how does delete[] works to delete the whole array.As here was not mentioned the size of the array. Then how does the statement `delete[] p;` delete the whole array.

Comment: Since `p` is just a pointer, the compiler and the standard library doesn't know that it points to the first element of an array, so you can't use the non-array `delete` operator. The compiler and standard library needs to know that you are freeing an array, which is why you need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude int reply to your:  you can't use the non-array delete operator. But it works delete p;

Comment: Try creating an array of an object whose destructor needs to be called, and it will no longer work. `new` *must* be matched with `delete`, and `new[]` *must* be matched with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the compiler to figure out how to do that.  One fairly standard way to do this is to store the size of the array in a technical header that precedes the allocated memory block.